# Setting textView to start at top (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I'm looking to have my textView in Xcode to start at the top because it is currently starting a little under the top.

```
 //This is the code I'm using currently to try and have it start at the top

 self.productDescription .scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
```

However this is not working. Anyone have any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UITextView element has contentInsets by default. You can try changing the values of the textView.contentInset like so:

`textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0);`